# Cannot find type 'UIViewRepresentable' in scope

Tags: swiftui, uiviewrepresentable

```swift
import SwiftUI
#if canImport(WebKit)
import WebKit
#endif

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {

    var url: URL

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    }
}
```

I created my app as a multiplatform app.  I added this view.  However I'm getting a couple errors that I can't figure out.

`Cannot find type 'UIViewRepresentable' in scope`
`Cannot find type 'Context' in scope`

I cleared my build folder.  My minimum deployment targets are as follows:

[image]

I want this to run for the following schemes:[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
UIViewRepresentable
```

Is for iOS and MacCatalyst

```
NSViewRepresentable
```

Is for macOS

Make sure that you are checking the target, you are likely building for macOS.

```
#if os(iOS)
     UIViewRepresentable code

#endif
```

Comment: When I tried doing @available for both i was getting errors, can you share some code that runs with that?

Comment: @ScottyBlades it is usually a target thing but you can use “if os” see above.